# Difference between Path, Curve, Graph and Trace

Tags: integration, general-topology

I am having difficulties in understanding the differences between these concepts. We have a new lecturer who loves writing down things in dense mathematical notation (I don't think that's bad but I am just not used to it) and I am not really getting anything. For example, here is how he defined a Path (translation from german):

Let $I\subsetneq \mathbb R$ be any Intervall and let $\vec{x}=I\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be any $\mathcal C^k$-map then we call $\vec{x}$ a $\mathcal C^k$-path with values in $\mathbb R$.

What does he mean by $\mathcal C^k$-path?

I hope my translation makes sense. I can't tell because I don't really understand what a path is in the first place. Maybe someone can help me understand these concepts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

A path in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous function $f$ from some interval $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. We can also not require the interval to be closed. Think of the image of any continuous function on $[a,b]$. Does it not look like you're moving on a path from $f(a)$ to $f(b)$ in the image, without "jumping" across points, as you go from $a$ to $b$ in the domain?

A $C^k$-path is a path that is differentiable $k$ times and has continuous derivatives on $[a,b]$ each time you differentiate. Since your domain is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, we just require that each component of your vector-valued function is in $C^k([a,b], \mathbb{R})$.

A graph of a function $f:X\to Y$ is the set of points $(x,y)$ for all $x \in X$.

I need more context to define a trace and a curve, but usually when people say curves, they mean the same thing as the path I just defined.

Note also that two different paths may have the same image. For example, $\gamma_1, \gamma_2: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, where $\gamma_1(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$, $\gamma_2(t) = (\cos(2t), \sin(2t))$ both have the same image of a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much. So a path is a special case of a function? Basically what is meant by a path is the literal path you take through the points $x, f(x)$ to get from $a$ to $b$?

Comment: Yep, the path is technically the function $f$ itself (we use the technical definition for proofs)  but you can see the "path" through its image as it goes from $f(a)$ to $f(b)$. Note that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ and all $f(x)$ are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and they may be arranged any way we want, so the path can go and twist in many ways. The only requirement is that the path is continuous, so it can't jump - that doesn't mean it can be easily drawn, however! There are very weird continuous functions like the Weierstrass function: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/WeierstrassFunction.svg

Comment: In Ross, they define path indeed as the continuous function $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R^n$, and the curve as $f([a,b])$.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of a path (to me) is just a $1$-dimensional curve that's parameterized. For example, if we walk around the top half of the unit circle, we can parameterize this path by

\begin{align*}\vec{x}: [0, \pi] &\to \Bbb R^2 \\
t &\mapsto \left(\cos t, \sin t\right).
\end{align*}

I believe the notation $C^k$ just stands for the class of functions that are differentiable $k$-times, and each of these derivatives are continuous. In the example above, since our circular functions have continuous derivatives of all orders, that's an example of a $C^\infty$-path.

I think it's a little odd referring to the *function* $\vec{x} : I \to \Bbb R^n$ as the path; normally we think of the *image* $\vec{x}(I) \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ as the path; the actual points in $\Bbb R^n$.

I assume, for traces, you're probably talking about things like [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/MultiVrbleFcns.aspx), near the bottom of that link. Essentially, you're focusing on what happens in a particular (hyper)plane. More context would probably be helpful for the rest; they may deserve their own questions.

Comment: Thanks. What does parameterize mean? I am really sorry if this is trivial stuff but a lot of this is very new to me.

Comment: No problem! Basically, a 'parameter' is a sort variable that changes things. Like if you had the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = y$, a general solution would be $y = Ce^{kx}$. We could think of the constant $C$ as a parameter: We change the value of $C$, and we get a solution; every solution is 'parameterized' by changing the value of $C$. The variable $t$ above behaves this way: as we change the value of $t$, we get new points on our path; every point on the path is obtained by using some $t$ in our interval.

Comment: Note my error above: The general solution would be $y = Ce^x$; I fixed one typo only to introduce another...